# Apache Http Async Client

Tags: apache, asynchttpclient

I am using Apache Async Http Client to make concurrent async API calls. I am wondering if it internally creates multiple threads to make concurrent requests

Answer (score 0):

It is using java nio, the event loop non-blocking style, by default it creates only 1 thread per core. e.g. 8 core machine = 8 threads.
FYR